# Why cannot this be answered this way ??

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The question is 
How many paths are there from the point $(0,0)$ to the point $(110,111$) in the plane such that each step either consists of going one unit up or one unit to the right?

The suggested answer : since we have $2$ possibilities for each step why cannot we say the probability is $2$ to the power of the total number of steps?

I understand he answer which is $221$ choose $110$ but I cannot figure out why the other one does not give the same answer.

Comment: First, probability of what? But let's consider the number of possibility is $2^{221}$. Then that means you don't rule out the possibility that you make $221$ horizontal steps. Do you see the problem?

Comment: Your count also includes the paths ending at $(111,110)$, at $(100,121)$ etc. etc.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut yes thank u now i totally understand it thank u so much

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown thank you I totally get it

Comment: You can't go up for $221$ steps.  You don't always have $2$ options.  You have $2$ options *until* you hit a wall.  But once you hit a wall you will have no choices.  So start with $2^{110}$ options but $2$ of those have no options.  And after $111$ steps several more end and you have not options.  The final result won't be $2^{221}$

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by @fleablood, you don't have two options *every move*, but instead $2$ options until you hit a wall.

Put more precisely: You must make *exactly* $110$ movements upwards and $111$ movements rightwards. You can however choose when to do the upward movements.

Once you decided in which of the $221$ steps you want to do the $110$ upward movements, the rightward movements are already given.

So you have $\displaystyle\binom{221}{110}$
possible paths.